# RMI app using standalone desktop

Tags: java, rmi

i am developing a application in which a desktop will be used as server(as few user will be there for that app) , i am using java rmi technology for communicating between several client and server.the stand alone desktop is under the network from where it will get hit. while running the server class i am getting such error:
Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
below is sample code i hv used--

```
  import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

public class MyServer{

public static void main(String args[]){
try{

Adder stub=new AdderRemote();
Naming.rebind("rmi://10.123.56.78:5000",stub);

}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}

}
```

Comment: have you try with    telnet 10.123.56.78 50000     from the command line ?

Comment: Yes telnet not working. But ping is working. I have tried cmd command rmiregistry 5000.still  It did not work. How do i configure port on a desktop

Comment: this is because you don't have access to the port, or your service is not listening on the port 5000. Ping is a different service, so it does not matter that the ping is working, it only says that you can reach the server but it does not say that you can reach the exposed service.

Comment: Then what next to do. Its just should i change the port. Or should i change firewl pilicy

Comment: You need to show your source code, so we can help you.

Comment: @neos Gee, what he posted sure looks like code to me. And he's not trying to contact his service, he's trying to contact the Registry. And firewalls don't cause connection refusals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no RMI Registry (or anything else) listening at 10.123.56.78 port 5000.

In fact when calling `Naming.bind()/rebind()/unbind()` there is little point in specifying the IP address at all, as you can only do those operations on a local Registry. It makes more sense just to specify`"localhost"` in these cases, and it makes your code portable too.

Why are you using port 5000?

Comment: So which port should i use. There is no service at that port.even there is no other service in that mechine. Its just  desktop connected to network.i need to configure all necessary things

Comment: You can use any free port you like, including 5000, but the standard RMI Registry port is 1099.